# React native function stack trace on error/crash

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have mobile app in react native.

I am having hard time to understand where error comes from /what is the cause, when i have some error on code.
both on production and debugging.

as may all of you know, the stack trace of react native is useless.

i have try and catch in all of my functions on code(which is a separate problem) that logging the error to firebase on catch.

but most of the stack traces looks like this:

```
" in GuideHomeDetails (created by Connect(GuideHomeDetails)) in Connect(GuideHomeDetails) (created by SceneView) in StaticContainer in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView) in SceneView (created by CardContainer) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by CardContainer) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by CardContainer) in RCTView (created by View) in View in CardSheet (created by Card) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by AnimatedComponent) in AnimatedComponent in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PanGestureHandler) in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler) in PanGestureHandler (created by Card) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by AnimatedComponent) in AnimatedComponent in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Card) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by Card) in Card (created by CardContainer) in CardContainer (created by CardStack) in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent) in AnimatedComponent in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen) in Suspender (created by Freeze) in Suspense (created by Freeze) in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze) in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen) in InnerScreen (created by Screen) in Screen (created by MaybeScreen) in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack) in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer) in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer) in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by Background) in Background (created by CardStack) in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext) in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView) in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView) in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView) in StackView (created by StackNavigator) in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent) in NavigationContent in Unknown (created by StackNavigator) in StackNavigator (created by GuideHomeStackScreens) in GuideHomeStackScreens (created by SceneView) in StaticContainer in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView) in SceneView (created by BottomTabView) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by Screen) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by Background) in Background (created by Screen) in Screen (created by BottomTabView) in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent) in AnimatedComponent in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen) in Suspender (created by Freeze) in Suspense (created by Freeze) in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze) in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen) in InnerScreen (created by Screen) in Screen (created by MaybeScreen) in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView) in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer) in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer) in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext) in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView) in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator) in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent) in NavigationContent in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator) in BottomTabNavigator (created by TabNavigator) in TabNavigator (created by Connect(TabNavigator)) in Connect(TabNavigator) (created by SceneView) in StaticContainer in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView) in SceneView (created by CardContainer) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by CardContainer) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by CardContainer) in RCTView (created by View) in View in CardSheet (created by Card) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by AnimatedComponent) in AnimatedComponent in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PanGestureHandler) in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler) in PanGestureHandler (created by Card) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by AnimatedComponent) in AnimatedComponent in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Card) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by Card) in Card (created by CardContainer) in CardContainer (created by CardStack) in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent) in AnimatedComponent in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen) in Suspender (created by Freeze) in Suspense (created by Freeze) in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze) in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen) in InnerScreen (created by Screen) in Screen (created by MaybeScreen) in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack) in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer) in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer) in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by Background) in Background (created by CardStack) in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext) in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider) in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext) in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView) in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView) in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView) in StackView (created by StackNavigator) in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent) in NavigationContent in Unknown (created by StackNavigator) in StackNavigator (created by Navigation) in EnsureSingleNavigator in BaseNavigationContainer in ThemeProvider in NavigationContainerInner (created by Navigation) in Navigation (created by App) in Provider (created by App) in App (created by CodePushComponent) in CodePushComponent in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by AppContainer) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by AppContainer) in AppContainer in mimimobile(RootComponent)"
```

it doesnt help me to understand the flow of the app (like what function called the failing function and what cause the function to fail)

what i am trying to achieve is that when some error will occur in the code, i will have as much info as possible, to know what is the cause and location of the error.
Both on production and debugging.

how can i achieve it?